# Fazer login no WebService via Android

Tags: android, json, web-service

E ai pessoal tudo tranquilo?

A minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Estou tentando criar uma tela de login no Android sendo que os dados cadastrados estão em um banco de dados Mysql, para estabelecer a comunicação eu tenho um WebService Rest funcionando, a questão é: estou enviando um GET para o meu servidor se ele encontrar os dados que eu solicitei ele me retorno o login e senha depois eu pego esses dados e comparo com os que foram digitados pelo usuário, creio que essa não seja a melhor maneira de fazer uma autenticação.
Gostaria que após o login tiver sido efetuado na tela seguinte aparecesse o nome da pessoa que fez o login.

Segue abaixo minhas classes do cliente Android:

**Classe UsuarioREST**

public class UsuarioREST {

```
private static final String URL_WS = "http://10.1.1.103:8084/ServidorWS/webresources/Usuario/";


public Usuario getUsuario(String login) throws Exception {

     String[] resposta = new Webservice().get(URL_WS+"Usuario/buscarLogin/"+login);

     if (resposta[0].equals("200")) {
         Gson gson = new Gson();
         Usuario usuario = gson.fromJson(resposta[1], Usuario.class);
         return usuario;
     } else {
         throw new Exception(resposta[1]);
     }
}
```

**Classe webService**

public class Webservice {

```
private HttpEntity entity;

public final String[] get(String url) {

     String[] result = new String[2];

     try {
         HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
         HttpResponse response;
         response = HttpClient.getHttpClientInstace().execute(httpget);
         entity = response.getEntity();

         if (entity != null) {
             result[0] = String.valueOf(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
             InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
             result[1] = toString(instream);
             instream.close();
             Log.i("get", "Resultado para o post JsonPost : " + result[0] + " : " + result[1]);
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e("NGVL", "Falha ao acessar Web service", e);
         //Log.e("NGVL", e.toString(), e);
         result[0] = "0";
         result[1] = "Falha de rede!";
     }
     return result;
    }
```

**MainActivity**

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
//private String id;
private String login;  
private String senha; 



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final EditText editLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLogin);
    final EditText editSenha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSenha);
    final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button btnLogar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butLogar);


    btnLogar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {       

        AsyncTask<String, Void, Usuario> atBuscaUsuario = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Usuario>() {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;


        @Override
        protected Usuario doInBackground(String... params) {
            login = editLogin.getText().toString();
            senha = editSenha.getText().toString();
            try {
                //testo se os campos login ou senha estão vazios
                if(editLogin.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){ 
                        gerarToast("Digite um login!");
                }else
                    if(editSenha.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
                        gerarToast("Digite uma senha!");
                }else{
                    UsuarioREST rest = new UsuarioREST();
                    Usuario usuario = rest.getUsuario(login);
                    return usuario;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                gerarToast(e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Aguarde", "Efetuando login...");
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Usuario usuario) {
            super.onPostExecute(usuario);

            if (usuario != null) {
                 if(login.equals(usuario.getLogin().toString().trim()) && senha.equals(usuario.getSenha().toString().trim())){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PedidosActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                 }else{
                     gerarToast("Senha incorreta!");
                 }
                //text.setText(usuario.getSenha().toString().trim());
            }

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };
    atBuscaUsuario.execute(login);
}



private void gerarToast(final String msg) {

    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

        }//fim do metodo onClick




    });//fim do evento setOnClickListener
```

}

Comment: Só pra entender: O login é uma activity, e a tela Principal(que você quer que apareça o nome) é outra activity? Você pode adicionar "extras" como parâmetro na Intent de Chamada para capturar o valor na outra tela.

Comment: Ve se esse exemplo ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-do-i-get-extra-data-from-intent-on-android

Comment: @Geferson
A tela de login é a activity principal (MainActivity), meu objetivo é fazer a autenticação e logo em seguida o usuário seria redirecionado para outra activity e nessa activity terá as opções que ele poderá executar, e claro já que o usuario x logou então gostaria que o nome dele ficasse aparecendo em algum lugar dessa activity secundária.

Comment: O que você pode fazer é o que foi sugerido acima, ao chamar a Intent passe o login/nome como extra, e na outra activity, pode ser no onCreate, recupere ele com String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?